# Python3: Save Column Vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using Spyder v-3.3.3 on Debian Stretch and have written a script to process data from another application.  I am having a problem saving the resulting file [A] as a column vector.

The vector is saved by  `np.savetxt(name_s,[A])`.

When I open the file in Spyder it is a column vector, but when I import the saved file into QtiPlot it is a line vector.

What am I missing in the savetxt statement?

Comment: What is the actual content of the file, when you open it in a text editor?